# Combine two python scripts for web search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to download files from a site and due to search result limitations (max 300), I need to search each item individually. I have a csv file that has a complete list which I've written some basic code to return the ID# column.

With some help, I've got another script that iterates through each search result and downloads a file. What I need to do now is to combine the two so that it will search each individual ID# and download the file.

I know my loop is messed up here, I just can't figure out where and if I'm even looping in the right order

```py
import requests, json, csv

faciltiyList = []
with open('Facility List.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for searchterm in csv_reader:
        faciltiyList.append(searchterm[0])

        url = "https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/FindFacility.aspx"
        r = requests.get(url+"?term="+str(searchterm))
        searchresults = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
        for report in searchresults:
            rpt_id = report['RPT_ID']
            reporturl = f"https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/DownloadPublicFile.aspx?archrptsegid={rpt_id}&reporttype=58&exportformatid=8&versionid=1&pageid=1"
            r = requests.get(reporturl)
            a = r.headers['Content-Disposition']
            filename = a[a.find("filename=")+9:len(a)]
            file = open(filename, "wb")
            file.write(r.content)
            r.close()
```

The original code I have is here:

```py
import requests, json

searchterm="ALAMEDA (COUNTY)"

url="https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/FindFacility.aspx"
r=requests.get(url+"?term="+searchterm)
searchresults=json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
for report in searchresults:
    rpt_id=report['RPT_ID']
    reporturl=f"https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/DownloadPublicFile.aspx?archrptsegid={rpt_id}&reporttype=58&exportformatid=8&versionid=1&pageid=1"
    r=requests.get(reporturl)
    a=r.headers['Content-Disposition']
    filename=a[a.find("filename=")+9:len(a)]
    file = open(filename, "wb")
    file.write(r.content)
    r.close()
```

The searchterm ="ALAMEDA (COUNTY)" results in more than 300 results, so I'm trying to replace "ALAMEDA (COUNTY)" with a list that'll run through each name (ID# in this case) so that I'll get just one result, then run again for the next on the list

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not clear on what is the question here, or what is the problem or error you are running into.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my knowledge of this is very limited..I'm trying to download files from a website. I need to search each facility individually to do this because of search limitations. I have a list, but I don't know how to run this list through the search. I was thinking for each item in the list, I could run the second batch of code (that starts with url=), but I don't know how to do this

Comment: Could you provide how your `Facility List.csv` looks like –– a few lines. Also, in the line `r = requests.get(url+"?term="+str(searchterm))`, did you intend to use the facility instead? So, shouldn't it be `searchterm[0]`.

Comment: "406010659,"HOLISTIC PALLIATIVE CARE, INC.",550004188,Parent Facility,5707 REDWOOD RD,OAKLAND,94619,1,ALAMEDA,Not Applicable,,Open,1/1/2018,Home Health Agency/Hospice,Hospice,37.79996,-122.17075" is the fist line, the rest follow that format. Yes, since searching the county gives me too many results, I'm thinking searching each one by their ID# is the way to go

Comment: Oh I see what you're talking about...I thought searchterm[0] became the variable searchterm, but you're saying I should still specify it in the requests.get() line?

Comment: Well, I don't see you setting `searchterm = searchterm[0]`, so it should still refer to the entire csv line you read from the file. Since you want to query just the ID, I'd suggest using the searchterm[0] in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CSV - just 1 line

Tested with a CSV file with just 1 line:

```
406014324,"HOLISTIC PALLIATIVE CARE, INC.",550004188,Parent Facility,5707 REDWOOD RD,OAKLAND,94619,1,ALAMEDA,Not Applicable,,Open,1/1/2018,Home Health Agency/Hospice,Hospice,37.79996,-122.17075
```

## Python code

This script reads the IDs from the CSV file. Then, it fetches the results from URL and finally writes the desired contents to the disk.

```
import requests, json, csv

# read Ids from csv
facilityIds = []
with open('Facility List.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for searchterm in csv_reader:
        facilityIds.append(searchterm[0])

# fetch and write file contents
url = "https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/FindFacility.aspx"
for facilityId in facilityIds:
  r = requests.get(url+"?term="+str(facilityId))
  reports = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
  # print(f"reports = {reports}")
  for report in reports:
    rpt_id = report['RPT_ID']
    reporturl = f"https://siera.oshpd.ca.gov/DownloadPublicFile.aspx?archrptsegid={rpt_id}&reporttype=58&exportformatid=8&versionid=1&pageid=1"
    r = requests.get(reporturl)
    a = r.headers['Content-Disposition']
    filename = a[a.find("filename=")+9:len(a)]
    # print(f"filename = {filename}")
    with open(filename, "wb") as o:
      o.write(r.content)
```

[Repl.it link](https://repl.it/@sidmishraw/data-read)